STM32-L432KC CAN mailboxes are not emptied HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM
Trying to send a CAN message every second but after a few tries it returns the HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM error.
Tried to check if there is an empty mailbox available before sending the next can message but the mailboxes arent emptied.
Below is the while loop from the main.
while (1)
  {
    //if the flag is high, one sample moment will occur
    if(sampleFlag == 1) {
        readWIT(WITsensor);
        //delay to allow the bus to clear
        HAL_Delay(3);

        readSenixSensors(&Senix1, &Senix2);

        if (HAL_CAN_GetTxMailboxesFreeLevel(&hcan1) != 0) {
            
            sendMessage();
        }

        sampleFlag = 0;
    }

Below are all the functions regarding CAN
void HAL_TIM_PeriodElapsedCallback(TIM_HandleTypeDef *htim){
    //check if the interrupt is triggered by the correct timer
    if (htim == &htim16){
        //create a variable delay
        if(currentDelay >= timeBetweenSamples) {
            sampleFlag = 1;

            currentDelay = 0;
        }
        else {
            currentDelay++;
        }
    }
}

void convertFloatArrayToInt(float floatArray[], uint8_t intArray[], uint8_t size, uint16_t scale){
    uint8_t j = 0;
    for (uint8_t i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        uint16_t scaledValue = floatArray[i] * scale;
        intArray[j] = (scaledValue & 0xFF00) >> 8;
        intArray[j+1] = scaledValue & 0x00FF;
        j += 2;
    }
}

void sendPartionalMessage(uint8_t TxData[], uint8_t TxDataArray[], uint8_t id, uint8_t begin) {
    TxData[0] = id;
    uint8_t j = begin;

    for(uint8_t i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        TxData[i] = TxDataArray[j];
        j += 1;
    }

    /* send TxData*/
    if (HAL_CAN_AddTxMessage(&hcan1, &TxHeader, (uint8_t*)TxData, &TxMailbox) != HAL_OK)
    {
        uint32_t error = HAL_CAN_GetError(&hcan1);
        Error_Handler (); //!Error triggered here!
    }
}

void sendMessage(){

    /* convert the values to a type we can send*/
    //convertFloatArrayToInt(WITsensor, WITvalues, WITarraySize, 1000);

    /* make a array size so it is devidable by 7 and can accomadate all the vales
     * WITarraySize * 2 accommodates for all the WIT values
     * + 2 accommodates for the Senix sensors
     * + 6 makes it devidable by 7*/
    uint8_t TxDataArray[WITarraySize * 2 + 2 + 6];

    TxDataArray[0] = Senix1;
    TxDataArray[1] = Senix2;

    for(uint8_t i = 2; i < WITarraySize * 2 + 2; i++) {
        TxDataArray[i] = WITvalues[i - 2];
    }

    /*send all the data in different messages*/
    sendPartionalMessage(TxData, TxDataArray, 'A', 0);
    sendPartionalMessage(TxData, TxDataArray, 'B', 7);
//  sendPartionalMessage(TxData, TxDataArray, 'C', 14);
//  sendPartionalMessage(TxData, TxDataArray, 'D', 21);


}

void CAN_TX_filter_init(void)
{
    TxHeader.StdId = 0x222;
    TxHeader.ExtId = 0;
    TxHeader.IDE = CAN_ID_STD;
    TxHeader.RTR = CAN_RTR_DATA;
    TxHeader.DLC = 8;
    TxHeader.TransmitGlobalTime = DISABLE;
}

Below is the CAN init fucntion
void MX_CAN1_Init(void)
{

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 0 */

  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 1 */

  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 1 */
  hcan1.Instance = CAN1;
  hcan1.Init.Prescaler = 8;
  hcan1.Init.Mode = CAN_MODE_NORMAL;
  hcan1.Init.SyncJumpWidth = CAN_SJW_1TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg1 = CAN_BS1_7TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeSeg2 = CAN_BS2_8TQ;
  hcan1.Init.TimeTriggeredMode = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoBusOff = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoWakeUp = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.AutoRetransmission = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.ReceiveFifoLocked = DISABLE;
  hcan1.Init.TransmitFifoPriority = DISABLE;
  if (HAL_CAN_Init(&hcan1) != HAL_OK)
  {
    Error_Handler();
  }
  /* USER CODE BEGIN CAN1_Init 2 */
  if (HAL_CAN_Start(&hcan1) != HAL_OK) {
        Error_Handler();
    }
  /* USER CODE END CAN1_Init 2 */

}

Postion in code where the error handler is triggered
Error code, translates to HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM
Error definition

error logs? or images?

@Rainb Added images and added comment in the code where the HAL_CAN_ERROR_PARAM occurs

I have absolutely no idea, but most likely is that the parameter is wrong.

One little bug here: TxData[0] = id; ... for(uint8_t i = 0 ... TxData[i] =.

@Lundin could you elaborate please?

You write to index 0 in the array at multiple times, the first write is lost.
